# Pandas Add filename to a Excel combined file

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a code that combines multiple excel files in 1 file, but I need to add a column with the name of the file used (filename).

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  

## Code gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('Combined.xlsx')
```

How do I do to add a column with the filename for each file used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `d["filename"] = file` When you load Excel file in for loop:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 

files = os.listdir(cwd)  

## Code gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        d = pd.read_excel(file)
        d["filename"] = file
        df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True) 

df.head() 
df.to_excel('Combined.xlsx')
```

Comment: That worked !! thanks
Question, I only need the las 4 digits of the filename.
It is possible to do that?

Comment: `file[-4:]` will do :)
But probably the last 4 digits will be just **xlsx** and I am not sure if this is what you want.
If you want to have last 4 digits EXCEPT file extension you should do:
`import os file = os.path.splitext(file)[0]` and apply `file[-4:]` on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict to collect your dataframes then combine them before exporting (and use `pathlib` instead of `os` module):

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

data = {}
for file in pathlib.Path().glob('*.xlsx'):
    data[file.name] = pd.read_excel(file)
pd.concat(data).to_excel('Combined.xlsx')
```

Note: if you want to get the filename without extension, use `file.stem` rather than `file.name`.

**Update**

> What about when the excel files to combine have more than 1 Sheet?

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

data = []
names = []
for file in pathlib.Path().glob('?.xlsx'):
    for df in pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None).values():
        names.append(file.name)
        data.append(df)
pd.concat(data, keys=names).to_excel('Combined.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks, very neat code.

What about adding the other Sheets of a given file?

Comment: Your code is combining the first Sheet (tab) of all the excel files in the folder.
But, what about when the excel files to combine have more than 1 Sheet ?

Comment: @AntonioIBC. Do you need to create a new column for sheet names like the column for file names?

Comment: No, I don´t need a column for the sheets names.
I need the information stored on ther other sheets of the excel book.
As the code is only combining the first sheet of all the Excel books on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one.**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 

files = os.listdir(cwd)  

## Code gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append([file]) # Here is the code to ADD filename 
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('Combined.xlsx')
```

Comment: This code modifies the original files,
alters the order of the columns...
?

Answer (score 0):

this slightly modified version worked perfectly for me..

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
os.chdir("/Path/to/file/")
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
 
for f in glob.glob("/Path/to/file/*.csv"):
  df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None) # make sure to apply correct settings (sep, parse_dates, headers, missing_values
  df["origin"] = f #add a column with a csv name
  df_all = df_all.append(df) #append new df to the "master" dataframe
 
df_all.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

Comment: I basically set the operating directory to the path to file and read file without header which worked better for my purposes.